# Randomly extract rows based on multiple conditions using vba

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-conditions

I have an audited file. I need to extract some rows and paste it on another sheet based on multiple conditions,

The excel sheet has auditor name in column A, region in column C and decision in column T(column T has multiple values such as valid, Invalid, etc, to be selected using dropdown menus.)

I need a VBA code which should extract 27 rows for each person's each region(each person works on multiple regions) which must contain all valid decisions and the remaining rows can be randomly selected from remaining decisions.

Finally if a person A works on 2 regions, uUS and UK, the final output must have 27 rows for A person's Us and 27 rows for A person's UK and similarly every person's rows.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please note that SO is not a code writing service. Pleas edit your question and include your code attempt and explain what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Dictionary and Collections to hold the row numbers for each person/region combination. Randomly select and then remove from the collection the required sample.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SampleData()

    Const SAMPLE_SIZE  27
    Const SEP = "~" ' key separator
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim Lastrow As Long, r As Long, rOut As Long
    
    Dim dict As Object, key, ar, k As String, msg As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1) ' input data
    
    ' fill dictionary
    With ws
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To Lastrow
            k = Trim(.Cells(r, "A")) & SEP & Trim(.Cells(r, "C")) ' name~region
            If Not dict.exists(k) Then
                dict.Add k, Array(New Collection, New Collection) ' valid, non-valid
            End If
             ' valid or not
            If LCase(Trim(.Cells(r, "T"))) = "valid" Then
                dict(k)(0).Add r
            Else
                dict(k)(1).Add r
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    ' output results for each person/area
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, x As Long, y As Long
    Dim col As Collection, m As Integer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets(2)
    With wsOut
        .Cells.Clear
        ws.Rows(1).Copy wsOut.Range("A1")
        rOut = 1
        For Each key In dict.keys
            n = 0
            
            ' do valid then others
            For m = 0 To 1
                Set col = dict(key)(m)
                y = col.Count
                
                ' select valid
                Do While n < SAMPLE_SIZE And y >= 1
                    x = Int(Rnd() * y) + 1 ' random selection
                    r = col.Item(x)
                    rOut = rOut + 1
                    wsOut.Range("A" & rOut & ":T" & rOut).Value2 = ws.Range("A" & r & ":T" & r).Value2
                    col.Remove x ' remove from collection
                    y = col.Count
                    n = n + 1
                Loop
        
            Next
            ' check enough found
            If n < SAMPLE_SIZE Then
                msg = msg & vbLf & n & " for " & key
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    If msg = "" Then
        MsgBox "Finished", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox msg, vbCritical, "Samples short of " & SAMPLE_SIZE
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Im new to vba and i tried pasting this in a new module and run, but it doesnt work, everything is getting deleted, thats all, please help me out@CPDI1802

Comment: @N S What is getting deleted ? Create a new workbook with 2 sheets. Put the data in Columns A,C and T on Sheet 1. The results are written to Sheet 2.